# How to identify the expected exception at runtime while unit testing?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, exception

I am unit testing an WCF application which calls an function. I need to test this function. I am creating proxy for it and when I am trying to unit test the method some exception is generated. I have tried the following code but could not test the method because of exception.
Consider that the type of exception generated is not fixed.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception),"A Exception is been Generated.")]
public void TestMethodProxy()
{
IServiceProxy obj=new ServiceProxy();
bool result=obj.DisplayMessage();
Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

Please suggest some good solution.. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not going to be a very valuable unit test, purely because you're tesing multiple units simultaneously:

- The WCF Client
- The transport to the service
- The service message formatters (both serializing and deserializing)
- The WCF Service Host
- Your WCF-based service.

This has walked you directly into the problem: if you're testing multiple units at-a-time, how can you determine which unit has failed?

The answer is: **Your unit tests should test units.**

If you want to test the internal functions of your service, simply create a new instance of that service outside of a WCF hosting environment and unit-test that. If you want to test your hosting and configuration, create a mock service, host it in WCF and invoke the service with a reliable client.

You need to break down your test into isolated units if you want them to give you useful information.

Comment: A "unit" is a matter of perspective.

I guarantee I can pick apart any unit test you've ever written into different layers of dependencies just like you have done here.

Comment: The lesson here is not to create redundant levels of indirection, but instead to simply observe where separation into smaller units makes isolation and identification of the causes of problems easier.

Comment: I agree with that but think that it is not always true that the sum of the parts is equal to the whole.

I mean that while it is important to have granular tests, I think it is likewise important that you can rapidly and repeatedly perform tests which incorporate configurations and network conditions into the scope of a single "unit".

Comment: I think I might be blurring the line between unit tests and load tests, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing WCF service is not abut testing proxies which just confirms that WCF internals are working or not. What you should test is the methods of your service by simply new-ing the service and testing it's methods. Here you can test expected exceptions that your service can throw.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a try catch in the test itself and handle all the different cases that way. That way you have more granular control

You can then do an Assert.Fail if the correct exception isn't caught in the test

```
try
{
 //Run code that throws exception
}
catch(SpecificException ex)
{
  //Assert ex for more details if needed
  return;
}
Assert.Fail();
```

Comment: But I just want to pass the test method after the exception is being generated. Currently the method is getting failed.

Comment: Yes, you pass the test in your catch. If the correct exception is caught, just return out of the test

Comment: Can you suggest this with an example, please?

Comment: @TGH I have already mentioned that the exception type is not known in advance it is dynamically generated so please consider it.

Comment: Well the test should be deterministic when it comes to what type of exception it's testing for. There must be a finite set of exception types, so I would create a test for each exception type.